# How can I convert String (with linebreaks) to HTML?

Tags: python

When I print the string (in Python) coming from a website I scraped it from, it looks like this:

```
"His this 

is 

a sample

String"
```

It does not show the `\n` breaks. this is what I see in a Python interpreter.

And I want to convert it to HTML that will add in the line breaks. I was looking around and didn't see any libraries that do this out of the box.

I was thinking BeautifulSoup, but wasn't quite sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a String that you have readed it from a file you can just replace `\n` to `<br>`, which is a line break in html, by doing:

```
my_string.replace('\n', '<br>')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the python `replace(...)` method to replace all line breaks with the html version `<br>` and possibly surround the string in a paragraph tag `<p>...</p>`. Let's say the name of the variable with the text is `text`:

```
html = "<p>" + text.replace("\n", "<br>") + "</p>"
```

Answer (score 5):

searching for this answer in found this, witch is likely better because it encodes all characters, at least for python 3
[Python – Convert HTML Characters To Strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-html-characters-to-strings/)

```
# import html
import html

# Create Text
text = 'Γeeks for Γeeks'

# It Converts given text To String
print(html.unescape(text))

# It Converts given text to HTML Entities
print(html.escape(text))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<pre>` HTML tag.

```
html = '<pre>' + my_string '</pre>'

<pre>
His this 

is 

a sample

String
</pre>
```

You don't need to care about `\n` or `<br>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want paragraphs (`<p>` tags) instead of breaks (`<br>` tags), you can use a regex:

```
import re

def text_to_html_paragraphs(text):
    # First, replace multiple newlines with a single newline,
    # so you don't get empty paragraphs
    text = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', text)

    # Split the text into lines
    lines = text.split('\n')

    # Wrap each line in a <p> tag and join them
    return ''.join(f'<p>{line.strip()}</p>\n' for line in lines)

text = """His this 

is 

a sample

String"""

html_paragraphs = text_to_html_paragraphs(text)
print(html_paragraphs)
```

**Result:**

```
<p>is</p>
<p>a sample</p>
<p>String</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work

```
for line in text:
   for char in line:
      if char == "/n":
         text.replace(char, "<br>")
```